# How does debugging with watch expression work in Java (with concrete example)?

Tags: java, debugging, constructor, watch

Can you please help me understand how Debugging with Watch works in Java? In my comments below I captured the values shown in the watch window.
A few upfront questions to discuss:

1. What does this notation mean, for example: "#73"?
2. When new Test(t2) is called to create the next object, t1 = t2 (as the constructor suggests). Is t1 in this context the attribute t1 that every Test instance variable has?
3. Can an attribute of a Test object (t1) be equal to a Test object (t2)? In this case does it mean they point to the same object, so they store the same address?
4. And why is #73 the value of t3.t1? Is it because t1 = t2 after running the constructor with an argument? Isn't it a little contradictory that t3.t1 = #73 because t1 = t2, but at the same time we can't use t3.t2 notation because t2 is not declared as a variable in the class Test?

Here is the code:

```
class Test {
    Test t1;
    Test() {}
    Test (Test t) { 
        t1=t;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Test t2 = new Test();   // t2 #73 ; t2.t1 null ; t1 = cannot access instance variable from static context
        Test t3 = new Test(t2);  // t3 #74 ; t3.t1 #73 ; t1 = cannot access instance variable from static context
        t3.go(); // prints "hi"
        Test t4 = t3.t1; // t4 #73 ; t4.t1 null
        t4.go(); // prints "hi"
        Test t5 = t2.t1; // t5 null
        t5.go(); // NullPointerException (is it because a null object can't invoke any method?)
    }

    void go() { System.out.println("hi");
    }

}
```

PS: Using Netbeans, I followed the next steps to debug and display watches:

- right click and set breakpoint on a line of code
- Ctrl+Shift+F5 to debug file
- Step into (F7)
- Step Over Expressions (F8)

In the watch window that displays I added on the + sign to add variables or expressions that I could watch as I "Stepped over".

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm assuming it's an internal netbeans id of some sort. Other would show that as Test@abdef943c.
2. Since t1 is not static it's per instance. So you set t1 for t3 but not for t2/4/5.
3. Sort of...in t1 you don't store the actual object, you store a pointer to a reference to the object. This means that t3.t1 can point to t2, while t4.t1 can point to the same object.

Since you've debuggins so nicely you know which values are null, and now you hopefully know why and it'll be easy to fix.